# winform host rendering issue

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, rendering, winforms-interop

I have a winform host in my application that hosts a datagridview.
Everything works well, but when data is loaded into the datagridview, the opacity of window changes and until I move the window physically it wont go away. Can you please tell me how should I fix it?
Thanks,

sample code:

```
            windowsFormsHost1.Child = _MyDataGrid;
            windowsFormsHost1.InvalidateVisual();
            windowsFormsHost1.InvalidateArrange();
            this.Height = 450;
            windowsFormsHost1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            windowsFormsHost1.UpdateLayout();
```

[image: picture of window rendering opacity]

Comment: because the whole application is in WPF and I am hosting datagridview (winform control) in it.

Comment: I ended up using some another datagrid for my work and left the idea of hosting datagridview in WPF!